# http4s decompress gzipped http response

Tags: scala, http, gzip, http4s

I try decompress gzipped simple response on client side.
What the appropriate way to do it with http4s?

```
import cats.effect.{Blocker, ContextShift, IO, Timer}
import java.util.concurrent._
import org.http4s.{Header, Headers, HttpVersion, Method, Request}
import org.http4s.client.{Client, JavaNetClientBuilder}
import org.http4s.implicits._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(global)
implicit val timer: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(global)

val blockingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
val blocker = Blocker.liftExecutorService(blockingPool)
val httpClient: Client[IO] = JavaNetClientBuilder[IO](blocker).create
val uriYandex = uri"https://ya.ru"

val lstHeader: List[Header] =List(
  Header("Accept","text/plain")
  ,Header("Accept-Charset","utf-8")
  ,Header("Accept-Encoding","*")
)

val request2 = Request[IO](Method.GET, uriYandex, HttpVersion.`HTTP/2.0`, Headers(lstHeader))
val httpReq = httpClient.expect[String](request2)
val app = httpReq.map(resString => resString)

app.unsafeRunSync
```

http4s version "0.21.3"
If I run it in IDEA Scala Worksheet. it works fine and output:

*res0: String = <html class="i-ua_js_no i-ua_css_standart i-ua_browser_ i-ua_browser-engine_ i*

But if I change ,Header("Accept-Encoding","*")  into ,Header("Accept-Encoding","gzip")
server return me gzipped content and output:

*res0: String =
" ??????????|?r?H??P?320???,Y??+d[v{??????"  ?????%??9?'&6&66f???????3 ?{????7?/?*

I have tried different decoders, but with this errors:

Failure(java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format)

Comment: FWIW, "Accept-Encoding: *" does not make any sense. What were you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I can't see response headers in both cases, but looks like that with "Accept-Encoding: *" server not compress response and with gzip, response is compressed.

Comment: If you don't want compression, the right thing to send would be "Accept-Encoding: identity". See <https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#header.accept-encoding>.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everybody. I solve my problem with next using of GZip.

```
import org.http4s.client.middleware.GZip
val gzClient = GZip()(httpClient)
val httpReq = gzClient.expect[String](request2)
val app = httpReq.map(resString => resString)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just send the `Accept-Encoding` header, because when you do `httpClient.expect[String]`, the HTTP client will try to decode the data as a string, and it doesn't know that it needs to decompress the data first.

Try using the [GZip middleware](https://http4s.org/v0.18/api/org/http4s/client/middleware/gzip$).

Comment: Yes, I feel that using Client GZip middleware is a solution. But there are no examples of using it.